# How can I carry out the operation of "withdrawing eth from an ERC20 contract into a wallet" from the onchain (i.e., from another contract)?

Tags: solidity, transactions, erc-20, address.transfer

In `MainContract`, I need to perform an atomic transaction which includes the following:

1. Transfer eth from `Contract1` (which is an ERC20 contract) into a given address
2. Change a state variable in `Contract2`

I'm having problem implementing the first part.

At present, what I have in mind is to add this in `Contract1`:

```
address public mainContract;

constructor(address _mainContract) public {
    mainContract = _mainContract;
}

function withdraw(address _to, uint256 _value) external {
     require(msg.sender == mainContract);
     _to.transfer(_value);
 }
```

And then to call function `withdraw` from a function in `MainContract`:

```
function execute(address _to, uint256 _value) external {
     require(msg.sender == owner);
     contract1.withdraw(_to, _value);
     contract2.update();
 }
```

But since `Contract1` is an ERC20 contract, I was hoping there would be a cleaner way.

Given that I'm the owner of all contracts here, is there a way for me to directly transfer eth from `contract1` to the specified address `_to`?

Something like `_to.transfer(_value, {from: address(contract1)})` perhaps?

Thank you!

Note: The reason why I've mentioned the second part (`contract2`) here, is because otherwise you could tell me something like - "well, just do it from the offchain and get it over with". I need both operations to take place within a single transaction, in order to make sure that nothing else happens in between.